# FFmpeg executable Chmod permission

Tags: android, permissions, ffmpeg, command

Trying to run FFmpeg command using executable file stored in Raw folder eclipse for android app. I am getting permission denied error and not able to resize video. How can i give right permissions from my java file.

Answer (score 2):

put this code in a static class or wherever you want:

```
public static void installBinaryFromRaw(Context context, int resId, File file) {
    final InputStream rawStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);
    final OutputStream binStream = getFileOutputStream(file);

    if (rawStream != null && binStream != null) {
        pipeStreams(rawStream, binStream);

        try {
            rawStream.close();
            binStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to close streams!", e);
        }       

        doChmod(file, 777);
    }       
}
public static OutputStream getFileOutputStream(File file) {
    try {
        return new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "File not found attempting to stream file.", e);
    }
    return null;
}

public static void pipeStreams(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[IO_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int count;
    try {
        while ((count = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error writing stream.", e);
    }
}
public static void doChmod(File file, int chmodValue) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("chmod");
    sb.append(' ');
    sb.append(chmodValue);
    sb.append(' ');
    sb.append(file.getAbsolutePath());

    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sb.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error performing chmod", e);
    }
}
```

And call it with this code:

```
private void installFfmpeg() {
    File ffmpegFile = new File(getCacheDir(), "ffmpeg");
    mFfmpegInstallPath = ffmpegFile.toString();
    Log.d(TAG, "ffmpeg install path: " + mFfmpegInstallPath);

    if (!ffmpegFile.exists()) {
        try {
            ffmpegFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create new file!", e);
        }
        Utils.installBinaryFromRaw(this, R.raw.ffmpeg, ffmpegFile);
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "It was already installed");
    }

    ffmpegFile.setExecutable(true);
    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(ffmpegFile.canExecute()));
}
```

Hope it´s useful!!

Comment: Thank you very much.I used the code exactly and it says ffmpeg is installed perfect.Now This is what i did to run the FFMpeg command - but it is not creating any output video.I have a external directory path for my input mp4 file and i added a string path for output mp4 file on external directory.
From my oncreate() i call 
installFFmpeg();
String inputPath = "external directory path"
String outputPath = "external directory path"
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg -i "+ inputPath+ " -s 480x320 "+ outputPath);
processComplete = process.waitFor();
What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Okay, try to download a terminal emulator like that (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.acr.shellterminalemulator&hl=es) into your phone and try first the command there. You should acces to your ffmpeg executable typing: "cd /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/cache" "./ffmpeg -i inputFile -y outputFile". First of all try a very simple command and see if the file is copied. The file name can´t have spaces. Try that and tell me what are the ouput.

Comment: I tried it and getting all gibberish data. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hr61t6setidll18/device-2013-11-25.png)

Comment: well.. You need to put the extension of each file (.mp4 or whatever) and, which executable file are you using?? are you sure it´s compiled correctly for android?? Do you want my ffmpeg file to try??

Comment: Yes my string path has .mp4 extension. Problems could be my executable. This is where i am downloading it [link](http://www.evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/) . I guess it is not compiled for android. Can i try with your executable ? I will be really grateful.

Comment: Yeah... your ffmpeg version is only for Mac. Try this one: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9xbR4X7h9CidjNqaWgtaFMwdmM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: (you need to unistall the app before reinstall it with the new file because if you don´t do that, your app won´t change it)

Comment: Thank you @GonzaloSolera. I just downloaded it. Trying it now.

Comment: So now it says that permission denied . See the error log here [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l5m1gjayioaaqdw/ErrorLogFFmpeg.rtf).

Comment: Ouh... I don´t know which can be the problem... Try to use this path instead of the one you have: /sd card/myapp/tmp/MyVideos/myapp video_035.mp4/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was out on vacation for last few days. Just picking up this issue from where i left - i will keep you posted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your Android app must have permissions to read and write to storage, in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />.
```

Another caveat is the path, `/storage/emulated/0/` is not available on all devices, you should use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to find the actual path.

Finally, there is an easy workaround instead of extracting ffmpeg from raw folder, rename `ffmpeg` to `lib...ffmpeg...so` and put it into directory `libs/armeabi` in your project.

Naturally, you will later run `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(getContext().getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir
+ "/lib...ffmpeg...so" +`whatever`)`

System installer will unpack the executable into `/data/data/your.package.full.name/lib` for you automagically.

Comment: Thank You Alex - i will give it a shot today and tell you how it goes.